# Supermassive Black holes at centers of galaxies

Tags: gravity, cosmology, black-holes

Why there is super-massive black holes at the center of our galaxy and other galaxies ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formation of supermassive black holes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148931/)

Comment: I stand by my answer to that question - that there are a bunch of different explanations - but Kyle Kanos explained it better: Nobody knows.

Comment: I thought this question was "why are they at the centers of galaxies (rather than elsewhere)?" A different question from "how do they form?"

Answer (score 2):

Because at the centre of the galaxy, there is much higher star density, and thus, much higher chances for having huge stars.

These stars will inevitably collapse, forming black holes. These black holes if located at the center of a galaxy, are able to easily gain more mass from nearby stars. Increasing their mass further and further.

So finally, we have super-massive black holes.

Comment: But why there is much higher chances for having huge stars at the center?.Is it related to centrifugal forces ?