# What does the value of the cosmological constant signify in layman's terms?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

The value of the cosmological constant is $Λ = 1.10 \times 10^{-52}$ m$^2$. What is it saying or conveying in layman's terms other than the obvious that the universe is expanding?

Comment: *What is it saying or conveying in layman's terms other than the obvious that the universe is expanding?* It doesn’t say that the universe is expanding. When Einstein first included a cosmological constant, it was to keep the universe static.

Comment: I made the correction - thanks. So if its saying that the universe is expanding. What is it saying?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552953/what-exactly-is-the-cosmological-constant check the answer here

Comment: Are you interested in the cosmological constant as a concept, or its specific value? We don't really have a good explanation for its value, as far as I know.