# How does blackholes become supermassive?

Tags: black-holes

I am not an expert in this field. I have seen documentaries on the Universe and have a basic idea of how black holes come to existence. When black holes form from supernovae they have a initial mass which is a factor of the progenitor's mass. My question is how do they evolve to the million/billion solar mass monsters lurking in galaxies?

In the same vein how do we explain the supermassive black holes in very old galaxies formed immediately after the big bang? Did they form immediately after the big-bang?

Comment: They coalesce.  It's really not that much different from solar system formation where masses come together through gravity--likewise gravity attracts black holes together.

Comment: Also see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167250/ which partly addresses your latter question.

Comment: I agree that it is duplicated. Please improved it.