# How does the mass of black holes become so much larger than an average star

Tags: black-holes

1. How does the mass of black holes become so much larger than the mass of an average star? Since black holes are formed from the collapse of large stars, how come the mass of black holes is of astronomical scale. (If I am  right, i heard there must be a limit to how big a star can become, beyond that it wont be stable?). so this scale of size of mass of super massive black holes does not seem to add up to me, unless they devours many stars nearby it. Any explanation?
2. Can there be a possibility a more than one larger black holes compete to be for center of a galaxy?

Comment: Also have a look at [Is there a limit as to how fast a black hole can grow?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167250/is-there-a-limit-as-to-how-fast-a-black-hole-can-grow) as this covers similar material.